# TS2345 - Unable to avoid ts-ignore on my mock

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I have written a mock that works perfectly fine, but I can't make it work with a `@ts-ignore`

```
describe('findAll', () => {
    it('should get all networks of the user', async () => {
      const userId = uuid();
      const allNetworksFromRepo = Array(3).fill(networkDataBuilder());
      const expectedNetworks = allNetworksFromRepo;

      const createQueryBuilder = jest
        .spyOn(networkRepo, 'createQueryBuilder')
        // @ts-ignore
        .mockImplementation(() => ({
          innerJoin: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
          getMany: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(allNetworksFromRepo),
        }));

      const retrievedNetworks = await service.findAll(userId);

      expect(createQueryBuilder).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(retrievedNetworks).toStrictEqual(expectedNetworks);
    });
```

```
TS2345: Argument of type 
'() => { innerJoin: jest.Mock<any, any>; where: jest.Mock<any, any>; getMany: jest.Mock<any, any>; }'
 is not assignable to parameter of type 
'(alias?: string | undefined, queryRunner?: QueryRunner | undefined) => SelectQueryBuilder<Network>'.  

 Type
 '{ innerJoin: Mock<any, any>; where: Mock<any, any>; getMany: Mock<any, any>; }' 
is missing the following properties from type 
'SelectQueryBuilder<Network>': getQuery, subQuery, select, addSelect, and 94 more.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one line of code. What about this solution?

```
  // @ts-ignore
  const createQueryBuilder = jest
    .spyOn(networkRepo, 'createQueryBuilder')
    .mockImplementation(() => ({
      innerJoin: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      where: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
      getMany: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(allNetworksFromRepo),
    }));
```

Comment: No actually the `@ts-ignore` is well-placed to make it work, I'd actually like to remove it entirely. :)

Comment: ```
TS2345: Argument of type 
'() => { innerJoin: jest.Mock<any, any>; where: jest.Mock<any, any>; getMany: jest.Mock<any, any>; }'
 is not assignable to parameter of type 
'(alias?: string | undefined, queryRunner?: QueryRunner | undefined) => SelectQueryBuilder<Network>'.  

 Type
 '{ innerJoin: Mock<any, any>; where: Mock<any, any>; getMany: Mock<any, any>; }' 
is missing the following properties from type 
'SelectQueryBuilder<Network>': getQuery, subQuery, select, addSelect, and 94 more.
```